# CORS policy Error after deploy Front to firebae back to heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, cors, mern

we are trying me and my friend to deploy a project that's locally fully working.

But now we deployed it (the front to firebase the back to heroku),
and now every request we got cors policy

```js
app.use(cors());

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
  );

  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if ("OPTIONS" == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/function", couponRoutes);

mongoose
  .connect(  `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qvs4c.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Thats the code for the back (I tried also without the allowcross domain) and nothing is working.

we are doing from the front regular axios request and its not working , hope for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure cors by passing a javascript object to configure it like the following

```js
const corsOptions = {
"origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 200
  "exposedHeaders": ['Content-Length', 'X-Requested-With', ' Authorization','Content-Type'],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

You should use this instead of your code to get cors working

if you have multiple origins use the following snippet

```js
var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000',
                      'http://yourapp.com'];
app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    // allow requests with no origin 
    // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
    if(!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));
```